Should we introduce a "brain-training" tag?
I'm highly sceptical of what is often presented under the banner of "brain training". That said, a lot of people are interested in the topic, and it seems to be to be a bit distinct from "training" in general. I.e., it typical involves doing basic exercises with the aim of developing some domain general ability. In contrast I associate "training" with actual training of skills, such as workplace training or training in sports where people practice skills with the aim of developing those actual skills.
Thus, I was hoping I could add a "brain-training" tag so that all such questions would be better linked.
What do people think?
I'd also think that the tag description would include a suitably critical view on the merits of brain training.
Questions under the brain training tag would include:

Is consistent dual n-back training likely to improve the performance of analysis (mathematics) students?
What does Lumosity's Flexibility measure?
How valid is Lumosity's Brain Performance Index and what normative information is available?
Training for the corpus callosum?
Does the "use it or loose it" principle apply to the brain?
Does cognitive training enhance dopamine release?


I'd also think that the tag description would include a suitably critical view on the merits of brain training.  Yes, I completely agree.  Not everyone reads the tag wikis, though, so perhaps one of us could whip up a canonical "skeptical" question.

@chuck I've put down a first draft of a tag wiki, but as the king of all things tag-related, I'd welcome any improvements. :-)

Looks good, I just made the tag links into tag icons and a did a couple of changes in wording.  If you want you can move the "see other tags" back into the excerpt, but none of our other excerpts have those designations.
